# How to import at .woff2 font and use it in a sass setting?

Tags: css, sass, fonts, gulp, font-face

I have a file `_variables.scss` which is part of a **sass** setup with **gulp**.

In this file, I have the ability to import a Google Font as follows:

```
$font: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,600,700" !default;
$font-family-custom-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif !default;
$font-family-base: $font-family-custom-sans-serif !default;
```

I am trying now to replace this font with a custom import from a `.woff2` file. I tried the following, but this seems not to work:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gellix';
  src:  url("../../assets/img/brand/Gellix-Bold.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("../../assets/img/brand/Gellix-Regular.woff2") format('woff2')
}

$font: "Gellix", sans-serif !default;
$font-family-custom-sans-serif: "Gellix", sans-serif !default;
$font-family-base: $font-family-custom-sans-serif !default;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write a separate @font-face for each font variant

In your case it should look like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gellix';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../../assets/img/brand/Gellix-Regular.woff2") format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gellix';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../../assets/img/brand/Gellix-Bold.woff2") format('woff2');
}
```

And then check the browser console to see if the paths you specified are correct

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: I tried this but now I have that its not compiling when I run gulp build. I basically gets stuck in one of the steps. What could be this an indication of?

Comment: I added it outside the gulp built, separate css import, not great but it works